# Subring of $M_7(\mathbb{Z}_2)$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_{128}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, vector-spaces

Let $A \subset M_7(\mathbb{Z}_2)$ be a subring such that no proper nonzero subgroup $V \subset \mathbb{Z}_2^7$ is invariant under all matrices in $A$. I suspect that $A \cong \mathbb{F}_{128}$, but I'm at a loss on how to show it... could anyone give me a hint or help me out?

Comment: what do you mean "no $V\subset \mathbb{Z}_2^7$ is invariant under all matrices in $A$"? It's probably a standard definition but I don't have much linear algebra and I'm just curious about this problem.

Comment: Do you mean $AV\ne V$ for all nontrivial subspaces $V$, or that $V^A=0$? (In other words, invariant setwise or elementwise?)

Comment: @mathers101 Here we consider $A$ as a $7\times 7$ matrix with entries in $\mathbb{Z}_2$, so for $x \in \mathbb{Z}_2^7$, we have a vector of length 7 with entries in $\mathbb{Z}_2$, so $Ax$ is a $7 \times 7$ matrix times a $7 \times 1$ vector and so outputs a $7 \times 1$ vector.

Comment: Any reason why you suspect that?  I'm not so sure -- the multiplicative group of $\mathbb{F}_q$ is cyclic; in particular that means there should be $a \in A$ whose minimal polynomial is $t^{127} - 1$, but minimal polynomials can have at most degree 7?

Comment: @user148177: The polynomial $t^{127}-1$ is not irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_2$, and the minimal polynomial of a generator of $\mathbb{F}_{128}$ does in fact have degree $7$.  Indeed, $\mathbb{F}_{128}$ acting on itself by multiplication is an example of a ring $A$ as in the question.

Comment: @EricWofsey Yes, you're right.  You can add in a ring.  Whoops

Answer (score 6):

The first sentence of the problem's statement says that $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^7$ is a simple $A$-module; hence, by Schur's Lemma, the ring $A' = \text{End}_A((\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^7)$ is a skew field. By the Artin-Wedderburn Theorem, $A'$ is a field, thus $A' \cong \mathbb{F}_{2^n}$ for some $n$. Since $A'$ acts on $\mathbb{Z}/2^7\mathbb{Z}$, the latter has a structure of an $\mathbb{F}_{2^d}$ vector space, hence $2^7 = (2^n)^d$ (where $d$ is the dimension of this vector space), so $n\,\vert\,7$. Thus, either $n = 1$ and $A' = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, or $n = 7$ and $A' = \mathbb{F}_{128}$, $d = 1$.

By the Jacobson Density Theorem, $A = \text{End}_{A'}((\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^7)$. If $A' = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, then $A = \text{Mat}_7(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$, but this is excluded by $A$ being a strict subset of $\text{Mat}_7(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$. Thus, $A' = \mathbb{F}_{128}$, and $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^7$ is a dimension $1$ vector space over $\mathbb{F}_{128}$, so $A \cong \text{End}_{\mathbb{F}_{128}}(\mathbb{F}_{128}) = \mathbb{F}_{128}$.

Comment: The standard name for the "double commutator theorem" is the [Jacobson density theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobson_density_theorem).

Comment: How "$A'$ acts on $\mathbb{Z}/2^7\mathbb{Z}$"?